# Error 500 Axios POST Request in Laravel chat using Pusher and Vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, pusher

I have a problem following this tutorial to implement a simple chat in Laravel using Pusher and Vue.js: [Link tutorial](https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/).

My app.js file in assets/js where I make the request is this one:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',

data: {
tweets: []
},
created() {
this.showTweets();
Echo.private('chat')
    .listen('TweetSentEvent', (e) => {
    this.tweets.push({
        tweet: e.tweet.tweet,
        user: e.user
});
});
},
methods: {
showTweets() {
    axios.get('/tweets').then(response => {
        this.tweets = response.data;
    });
},
 addTweet(tweet) {
    this.tweets.push(tweet);

    axios.post('tweets', tweet).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
}
}
});
```

My web.php routes:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'TweetController@index');
Route::get('tweets', 'TweetController@showTweets')- 
>middleware('auth');
Route::post('tweets', 'TweetController@sentTweet
```

My controller is this one:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index()
{
    return view('chat');
}

public function showTweets(){
    return Tweet::with('user')->get();
}

public function sendTweet(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::user();

     $tweet = $user->tweets()->create([
        'tweet' => $request->input('tweet')
     ]);
    broadcast(new TweetSentEvent($user, $tweet))->toOthers();

    //return ['status' => 'Tweet Sent!'];

}
```

When I'm running the app and I try to send a tweet through a POST request clicking on my send button, this error apperas on the console:

```
POST http://localhost/youChat/public/tweets 500 (Internal Server Error)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
at createError (app.js:13931)
at settle (app.js:35401)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:13805)
```

Everything seems to be fine... Any help? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please share you api routes aswell.

Comment: Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/', 'TweetController@index');
    Route::get('tweets', 'TweetController@showTweets')- 
     >middleware('auth');
    Route::post('tweets', 'TweetController@sentTweet'             Here it is, thanks!